# Hide icon on each last item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested list with some items

[image: my nested list example]

Currently I'm displaying an arrow for each item, which results in a problem - if item has no sub-items, it still shows an arrow.

`ListItem` code (`className`s are excluded for a better reading):

```
function CodeItem({ props }: CodeItemProps) {
  const cpvs = Object.keys(tree) as Array<CpvLabelKey>;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(cpvs.some(c => codes.includes(c)));
  
  return (
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <div >
          <button
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
            aria-expanded={open}
          >
             // this icon should be displayed only if Item has sub-elements
            <UilAngleRight/>
          </button>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={`cpv-${code}`}
            id={`cpv-${code}`}
            checked={checked}
            onChange={e => onChange(e.target.checked, code)}
          />
        </div>

        <label htmlFor={`cpv-${code}`}>
          {code} - {tCPV(code)}
        </label>
      </fieldset>

      // where I map each Item
      {open && (
        <div>
          {cpvs.map(code => (
            <CodeItem
              key={code}
              code={code}
              onChange={onChange}
              tree={tree[code]?.children || {}}
              checked={codes.includes(code)}
              codes={codes}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How could I hide arrow on last elements, which has no over sub-elements?

Comment: Hi MiRAY! Can you make this code reproducible? Things are incomplete, for example, where is `tree` defined? Also there are many details which are irrelevant.

Comment: I see you are passing `tree` as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the array is not empty before rendering the icon

```
{!!cpvs.length && <UilAngleRight/>}
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r good catch, I forgot!

Comment: I was looking exactly for this - a validation before rendering the icon. Thanks!

Comment: To notice: I got an eslint warning (Redundant double negation), so I used `{cpvs.length && <UilAngleRight/>}` instead

Comment: @MiRAY but if the length is 0, then React will render a 0 to the page. Probably not what you want. You can do `cvps.length > 0` instead.